Cap thick metal pipe from bathroom radiator
Have this very old radiator. Need to remove it completely. Supply pipes have not been in use for many years, so needs to be capped.
Is it possible to do it myself, what tools? Or need a heavier tool from a plumber?


Thank you.

Can you move stuff to make room enough to work?  Two good/big pipe wrenches might do it, but have a feeling that start with metal cutting tools(angle grinder, metal saw) might lead to less words that young ones should not hear.

@crip659 thanks, I doubt it is possible to twist/disconnect these with wrench. It seems to me cutting is the only option.

If you know where the origination end of the pipe is, make sure that end is capped or otherwise made so somebody cannot reconnect water to it.
Then cut the pipes as close to the wall as possible and cover the scar on the wall. Use a hack saw, oscillating tool with metal cutting blade, reciprocating saw with metal cutting blade, or grinder with a metal cutoff wheel.
If you don't have any of those tools, go to a tool rental store and tell them what you want to do and they will give you suggestions as well.

Thanks but my question is what to use to cut them. The lines are completely dry, deactivated and won't be used in the future. What tools should I use to cut the thick old rusty pipes (both sides)?

Edited that info in.

thanks, what blade would you use in a hack saw?

24 or 18 TPI (teeth per inch) bi-metal hacksaw blade. For hacking through thick metal...

There are options, depending on how important the cosmetics are, ease of access, what tools you have and and how much effort and $ you want to spend.  I would recommend whichever option fits your situation:
Option 1 - Cutting the pipe from inside the room and covering the stub:  It's hard to cut flush with a wall, let alone recess it so you can patch it flat.  If you're okay with, say, making a cover to accommodate a bump-out, you could cut the pipe per @crip659 or @RMDman.  My preference would be:

Quickest but big angle grinder with metal cutting blade, $20
Quick but bigger and difficult to control reciprocating saw with metal cutting blade, $35
Slow but agile oscillating tool with metal cutting blade, $25
Very slow but agile hacksaw with metal cutting blade, $15

Option 2: Cutting the pipe from inside the room, below the surface so you can tile (or whatever) over it:
Using either an angle grinder or an oscillating tool, cut into the tile and plaster an inch or two from one direction and then the other, to remove a wedge.  That makes the hole wider as well as deeper, but if you're patching anyway, not much more trouble.  If you're going to replace a tile, cut along a joint.  Use a metal cutting blade for the pipe; it should be ok for a little plaster, but for the tile, I would use this with the angle grinder or this for the oscillator.
Option 3:  Removing the pipe from inside the room:
Do you have access to the other end (hidden from view in this room)?  If you can cut there (using any of the tools above), you'll be able to pull the pipes out from the front and fill in the holes flush to the wall.
Or, instead of cutting the pipes, you may be able to remove them from within the room using one of the various pipe and nipple extractors, also here, $10-$35.  These fit inside the pipe end, expand and grip as you turn the head with a socket wrench.  They can be a lot easier to work in a small space, and standard extensions and angle joints let you work the tool more efficiently than a pipe wrench.
